# shell script to join 2 files on basis of 2 columns and if a match found then write some fields

Tags: shell, shell-script

abc.csv

```
TBL_NAME,SANDBOX_NAME,SCRIPT_NAME
ccti_prod_attdnl_ext,abs_ext,101_ext_table.m_diag.pset
ccti_prod_attdnl_ext,abs_ids,101_ext_table.m_diag.pset
```

xyz.csv

```
PID,SANDBOX_NAME,SCRIPT_NAME
11065,abc_ext,101_ext_table.m_diag.pset
11066,abc_ext,101_ext_table.m_diag.pset
11067,abc_ids,101_ext_table.m_diag.pset
```

I want to join abc.csv and xyz.csv on basis of the fields $SANDBOX_NAME and $SCRIPT_NAME and the output condition are as follows

1. If there is one/unique match then need to write the values of $PID,$SANDBOX_NAME,$SCRIPT_NAME to a file.
2. If there are no matches then populate the value of $PID to NULL and write  the contents to a file in the following format as $PID=NULL,$SANDBOX_NAME,$SCRIPT_NAME

As of now my code looks like

```
awk -F',' 'NR==FNR{c[$2$3]++;next};c[$2$3] > 0' abc.csv xyz.csv | 
while read line
do
    PID=$(echo $line | cut -f 1 -d",");
    SAND_NAME=$(echo $line | cut -f 2 -d",");
    OBJECT_NAME=$(echo $line | cut -f 3 -d",");
    for ( $line >  
         echo "$SAND_NAME,$OBJECT_NAME,$PID" > test.csv
    done
```

Can you please have a  look and suggest me with your ideas so that I can complete my piece of code.Looking forward for your brilliant suggestions and ideas.
Appreciate your help and support.

Comment: Thanks for the good info good sample data and code.  One thing that will really help come up with a good answer quick is if you give examples of the outputs so the developers can visualize the answer more quickly.  It takes much longer to read the description _and_ imagine the sample output.  You know what you want, show us!  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, please show us your desired output. It is much easier to understand that way. Also, your code is broken, what is `for ($line >` supposed to be doing? And what do you mean by `NULL`? Do you mean an empty field (`,,`)? An actual NULL character (`\0`)? the string `NULL`? Nothing? Something else?

Comment: Seems to me that the entire thing can probably be done in a single `awk` script, you don't need to pipe the output to a shell loop.

Answer (score 0):

Using `bash`:

```
join -t @ -1 2 -2 2 -o2.1,1.2 -a 1 -e NULL \
    <( sort -t @ -k2 <( sed 's/,/@/' abc.csv ) ) \
    <( sort -t @ -k2 <( sed 's/,/@/' xyz.csv ) ) | sed 's/@/,/'
```

With the two files

```
TBL_NAME,SANDBOX_NAME,SCRIPT_NAME
ccti_prod_attdnl_ext,abc_ext,101_ext_table.m_diag.pset
ccti_prod_attdnl_ext,abc_ids,101_ext_table.m_diag.pset
ccti_prod_attdnl_ext,xxx_ids,101_ext_table.m_diag.pset
```

(`abc.csv` from the question, with `abs` replaced by `abc` and a non-matching line added) and

```
PID,SANDBOX_NAME,SCRIPT_NAME
11065,abc_ext,101_ext_table.m_diag.pset
11066,abc_ext,101_ext_table.m_diag.pset
11067,abc_ids,101_ext_table.m_diag.pset
```

(`xyz.csv` from the question), this produces

```
PID,SANDBOX_NAME,SCRIPT_NAME
11065,abc_ext,101_ext_table.m_diag.pset
11066,abc_ext,101_ext_table.m_diag.pset
11067,abc_ids,101_ext_table.m_diag.pset
NULL,xxx_ids,101_ext_table.m_diag.pset
```

The `join` operates on the result of replacing the first comma by `@` (any character not present in the data, at least not in the first field) and sorting each input file on the second `@`-delimited field (which is the last two comma-separated fields).  It outputs the first field from the first file and the second field from the second file. It also adds the unmatched entries from the first file and replaces empty fields with the string `NULL`.

The `sed` at the end then replaces the `@` with commas.